# Plotly.js: Why do I have to use a nested array when updating a plot?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly.js

[This example](https://plot.ly/javascript/streaming/#30-points-using-update) states that a plot is updated using

```
var newArray = []
...
newArray.splice(0, 1)
...
var data_update = {
   y: [newArray]
 };

Plotly.update('graph', data_update)
```

But why do I have to wrap the array of numbers into another array to make it work?

I read the docs and examples for [plotly.restyle](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle) and [plotly.update](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyupdate) but could not find an explanation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the doc to [Plotly.restyle](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle):

> In restyle, arrays are assumed to be used in conjunction with the trace indices provided. Therefore, to apply an array **as a value** , you need to wrap it in an additional array. For example:

```
// update two traces with new z data
var update = {z: [[[1,2,3], [2,1,2], [1,1,1]], [[0,1,1], [0,2,1], [3,2,1]]]};
Plotly.restyle(graphDiv, update, [1, 2])
```